# In Java String Class implements Comparable Interface,but StringBuilder and StringBuffer does not Implements Comparable Interface

Tags: java, collections

Hi i am trying to add StringBuffer object in treeset, but i got ClassCastException,because StringBuffer does not implement Comparable Interface, which String does. I would like to know the reason why StringBuffer and StringBuilder does not implement Comparable Interface implicitly.

```
TreeSet s = new TreeSet();
s.add(new StringBuffer("A"));
s.add(new StringBuffer("B"));
```

Comment: Well, according to the docs, Comparable `  imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. ` . I am not sure, how a class which implements the Builder pattern can really be sorted ... So for such cases, you should fall back to plain old String objects.

Comment: They are mutable. It's hard to compare two things that are changing.

Comment: Comparing two Strings is very common but I can't think of any situation where I have needed to compare two StringBuffers or StringBuilders.

Comment: Are you asking for the philosophical design tradeoffs argument the original creator(s) of StringBuffer/StringBuilder went through to decide whether or not to implement this interface?

Comment: If you really want to do that, you could use the constructor that accepts a `Comparator`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it means we cant compare StringBuffer and StringBuilder directly,first we need to convert it to a String Object.